# Robomongo - autoformat code

Tags: robo3t

How to autoformat code in Robomongo/Robo 3T? A shortcut will be handy too. I have looked into menus and a [list of shortcuts](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paralect/robomongo/master/shortcuts.txt) but couldn't find it.